# Canvas.GetTop() returning the same Y value for every control

Tags: .net, wpf

I am trying to build a series of controls in tree form into a canvas, then draw lines between them. First, I add all the controls to the canvas to get the ActualWidths. Then I have a recursive function that traverses the tree and gets each control's X and Y, then draws them all in their correct positions with spacing between each row and column, then draws lines between each parent and child.

I am having trouble with the lines. Each line is calculating the X correctly, but Canvas.GetBottom() and Canvas.GetTop() seem to return the same Y for every control, which makes the top of each line draw from the same Y with different X positions. Here is the code:

```
    public static void DrawMap(List<TreeNode> nodes, MapViewControl mapControl)
    {
        mapControl.MainCanvas.Children.Clear();

        if (!nodes.Any()) return;

        //Vertical pointer is used throughout the draw method to calculate the Y of each row
        var verticalPointer = NodeTopSpacing;

        //Used to center the row around the canvas midpoint when drawing
        var canvasMidpoint = mapControl.MainCanvas.Width / 2;

        //var start;
        var first = nodes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.IsStartingNode);
        if (first == null) return;

        var firstSelected = first.NodeBuilderNodeContainer.IsSelectedNode;

        //Add each control as a child to the canvas to calculate the ActualWidth and ActualHeight for later calculation
        CreateControls(first, mapControl.MainCanvas); 

        var rowDict = new Dictionary<int, List<NodeBuilderNodeContainer>>();
        rowDict[0] = new List<NodeBuilderNodeContainer>() { first.NodeBuilderNodeContainer };

        //Recursive method that gets each control's row number, adding it to rowDict
        CreateContainerRowMap(first.NodeBuilderNodeContainer, 0, rowDict);

        //Draws the controls by calculating the X and Y offset from each of othe other controls in the row/column
        DrawContainerRow(0, rowDict, mapControl.MainCanvas, verticalPointer, canvasMidpoint, firstSelected); 
    }

    public static void CreateControls(TreeNode node, Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (node?.NodeBuilderNodeContainer == null) return;


        canvas.Children.Add(node.NodeBuilderNodeContainer);
        node.NodeBuilderNodeContainer.InvalidateArrange();
        node.NodeBuilderNodeContainer.UpdateLayout();

        foreach (var c in node.NextNodes) CreateControls(c, canvas);
    }

    public static void CreateContainerRowMap(NodeBuilderNodeContainer node, int currentRow, Dictionary<int, List<NodeBuilderNodeContainer>> rowDict)
    {
        if (!node.Node.NextNodes.Any()) return;

        var children = node.Node.NextNodes.Select(n => n.NodeBuilderNodeContainer).ToList();

        foreach (var c in children)
        {
            if (!rowDict.ContainsKey(currentRow + 1)) rowDict[currentRow + 1] = new List<NodeBuilderNodeContainer>();
            if (!rowDict[currentRow + 1].Contains(c)) rowDict[currentRow + 1].Add(c);
            CreateContainerRowMap(c, currentRow + 1, rowDict);
        }
    }

    
    public static void DrawContainerRow(int row, Dictionary<int, List<NodeBuilderNodeContainer>> rowDict, Canvas canvas, double verticalPointer, double canvasMidpoint, bool lastRowContainedSelected)
    {
        if (!rowDict.ContainsKey(row) || !rowDict[row].Any()) return;

        if (lastRowContainedSelected) verticalPointer -= 2;

        var nodeContainers = rowDict[row];

        var rowWidth = nodeContainers.Sum(c => c.ActualWidth + NodeSideSpacing);
        var halfRowWidth = rowWidth / 2;

        var maxHeight = nodeContainers.Max(n => n.ActualHeight);

        
        var leftOffset = 0d;
        foreach (var c in nodeContainers)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(c, verticalPointer);
            Canvas.SetBottom(c, c.ActualHeight);
            var left = canvasMidpoint - halfRowWidth + leftOffset;
            if (c.IsSelectedNode) left -= 4;
            Canvas.SetLeft(c, left);
            var right = left + c.ActualWidth;
            Canvas.SetRight(c, right);

            leftOffset += c.ActualWidth + NodeSideSpacing;

            if (c.Node.PreviousNode != null) DrawLineBetweenNodes(canvas, c.Node.PreviousNode.NodeBuilderNodeContainer, c);
        }
        
        DrawContainerRow(row + 1, rowDict, canvas, verticalPointer + maxHeight + NodeTopSpacing, canvasMidpoint, lastRowContainedSelected);
    }



    public static void DrawLineBetweenNodes(Canvas canvas, NodeBuilderNodeContainer upperNode, NodeBuilderNodeContainer lowerNode)
    {
        var topName = upperNode.Node.NodeName;
        var lowerName = lowerNode.Node.NodeName;

        var line = new Line();
        line.X1 = Canvas.GetLeft(upperNode) + (upperNode.ActualWidth / 2);
        line.Y1 = Canvas.GetBottom(upperNode);
        line.X2 = Canvas.GetLeft(lowerNode) + (lowerNode.ActualWidth / 2);
        line.Y2 = Canvas.GetTop(lowerNode);

        line.StrokeThickness = 5;
        line.Stroke = Brushes.White;
        line.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;

        canvas.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

And the XAML for the control being inserted:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DialogTreeEditor.Controls.NodeBuilderNodeContainer"
       //Other unimportant namespaces here
         Width="Auto"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">


<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="0"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border BorderThickness="{Binding SelectedBorderThickness, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="8 8 8 0" Background="DarkGray">
            //Other unimportant content here
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image: X values being correctly calculated, but Y values all reflect the bottom of the topmost node]

Why is Y being calculated at the same value from Canvas.GetBottom() and Canvas.GetTop() no matter which control I pass into it?

Answer (score 0):

Likely your problem is that that you are setting all four attached properties, but you should only set two out of the four. See

https://wpf.2000things.com/2013/04/26/807-setting-the-position-of-child-elements-in-a-canvas-from-code/

Usually you will just want to set Left and Top, and the width and height of the element that you are positioning will be reflected when the element is rendered - you don't want to actually set the attached Right and Bottom properties.